# How to average column values every n rows in pandas

Tags: pandas, average

Could you let know how to average column values with same value in the first column as below? I'd like to calculate calculate every n rows of all columns. for example, the average of all the values from a1~a6 with site value '1' equals to 3. (my data has numerous columns and rows)

```
raw = {'site':['1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2'],
       'a1':['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'],
       'a2':['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'],
       'a3':['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'],
       'a4':['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'],
       'a5':['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'],
       'a6':['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
      }
df_tmp = pd.DataFrame(raw,columns = ['site','a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6'])
print(df_tmp)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) + mean for each site with [`GroupBy.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html)

```
# df_tmp = df_tmp.astype(int) # get correct result
df_tmp.melt('site').groupby('site')['value'].mean()
```

Or:

```
# df_tmp = df_tmp.astype(int) # get correct result
df_tmp.set_index('site').stack().groupby(level=0).mean()
#df_tmp.set_index('site').stack().mean(level=0) # .mean(level=0) deprecated
```

**Output**

```
site
1    3.333333
2    7.333333
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: thx so much! it definitely works

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
df.mean(axis=0) # by each row
df.mean(axis=1) # by each column
```

Also you may do the following:

```
df[[list_of_columns]].mean(axis=0)
df[[list_of_columns]].mean(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df_tmp.iloc[row_index, col_index]` to slice with index or `df_tmp.loc[row_index, list_of_col_name]` to slice with col_name and row index.

For this case:
`df_tmp.loc[0:3,['a1']]` returns

```
  a1
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
```

`df_tmp.iloc[0:3,1:5]` returns

```
  a1 a2 a3 a4
0  1  2  2  2
1  2  3  3  3
2  3  4  4  4
```

To get the mean value, you basically take the sliced df, and call `mean()`
`df_tmp.iloc[0:3,1:5].mean(axis=0)` will calculate mean value in respect of each col.

```
a1    41.0
a2    78.0
a3    78.0
a4    78.0
```

To calculate the mean value of the whole sheet, you can do something like...

`df_tmp.iloc[0:3,1:5].mean().mean()` returns `68.75`